# What's up with this simple mod-rewrite rule?

Tags: ajax, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, web-crawler

As part of Google's approach to crawling AJAX-populated content, I've got the following in a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

#snapshot requests
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^.*$ system/snapshot_mode.php?project=%1
```

I trigger the rule with a URL like

```
http://myserver.co.uk/?_escaped_fragment_=token
```

...but it fails to go to the page specified. It **does**, however, if I remove the query string part of the redirect, i.e. change it to

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ system/snapshot_mode.php
```

What's up with that?

[EDIT]

I added a `[R-302]` to the rule and it now tries to redirect me to the script BUT via a mangled, local machine filepath, i.e.

```
http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/docula/system/snapshot_mode.php?project=token
```

...and gives me a 403 access denied error.

Comment: if you add `[R=302]` flag to `RewriteRule` - where does it redirect you?

Comment: `and gives ms a 403 access denied error. WTF?` it is ok, as you can see - it parses and substitute everything. Do you have your .htaccess in the root of the server or in one of the folders?

Comment: It's one level down from the root.

Comment: `It's one level down from the root` then you need to add `RewriteBase /folder`, try with it.

Comment: Thanks - it now redirects. However: 1) It no longer silently redirects; the URL visibly changes. How to revert to silent redirection? 2) How come the root-anchored path is required? I would have thought the path would be executed relative to the location of the .htaccess file. The relative URL did work, but only if the query string was omitted. Still not really sure what this is all about!

Comment: Replace now `[R=302]` with `[L]`  This is how Apache is making redirect - read here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase

Comment: OK, now it fails to redirect. Again, though, if I remove the query string part, i.e. `?project=%1`, it redirects.

Comment: Did you add `[L]` flag? Try to add `[L,QSD]` (works in Apache 2.4 and above) to remove the _escaped_fragment_ part. Or  `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=([^&]+)`. If none of these helps - you can try to add logging to see what happening there http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging

Comment: No dice, I'm afraid. With the 302 it will redirect, with the query string, but not silently. With L it won't redirect with the query string, and the other two suggestions didn't change anything. I'm going to retire the issue for tonight but thanks a huge amount for your help - you're a credit to SO.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not reproduce your problem as it is working on my server without the problem. Also, try to clean the cache of the browser, if you had once a 301 redirect during the debug, browser caches it respond.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^.*$ system/snapshot_mode.php?project=%1 [L,QSA]
```

**RewriteRules and Query String**:

- By *default*, a `RewriteRule` does not change the query string. Therefore, QueryString is not required in the RewriteRule. If you are not adding a parameter to the replacement URL, `RewriteRule` passes on the incoming query string unchanged.
- If you are adding *new* parameters, the original query string will be discarded and the rewritten URL will get only the new parameters.
- If you want to combine the original query string and the new parameters, you can append it using the `Query String Append` [**QSA**] flag.

In your code, you have a new parameter `project=%1` without the [QSA] flag and therefore the `_escaped_fragment_=([^&]+)` parameter is discarded, making the **RewriteCond**ition fail.

---

**Also Note:**

- [R-302] is incorrect syntax. It should be [R=302]
- [QSD] - Query String **Discard** flag is not something we would want in this case.